# pulling images from firebase without onSnapshot React-Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

```js
export default class ImagesScreen extends React.Component {

  state = {
    user: {}
  };

  unsubscribe = null;

  componentDidMount() {
      const user = this.props.uid || Fire.shared.uid;

      //snapshot updates the document so it erases the old one.
      this.unsubscribe = Fire.shared.firestore
          .collection("images99")
          .doc(user)
          // .get()//here until end of catch is new
          // .then(function(doc) {
          //   if (doc.exists) {
          //       alert("image uploaded");

          //       doc => { this.setState({ user: doc.data() }) };
          //       console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
          //   } else {
          //       // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
          //       alert("image NA");
          //       console.log("No such document!");
          //   }
          // }).catch(function(error) {
          //   console.log("Error getting document:", error);
          // });

          .onSnapshot(doc => {
              this.setState({ user: doc.data() });
          });
```

In other js files I can upload images to firebase.  Problem is my ImageScreen.js (above).  I can get it so that the image that I upload appears using onSnapshot, but the problem is of course whenever I add a new photo snapshot updates it which I don't want.

I am trying to set up a gallery page where, after I upload them to firebase, I want to pull the data down into my js file above. I am still pretty new to React Native.

Note* above code currently runs, the commented lines are things I have tried etc to get it working without snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using onSnapshot if you do not want realtime updates.

Instead use get() , check this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data).